# Unable to do POST Rest Service using Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, rest, post, spring-boot

I am unable to do POST using AngularJs and REST services in Spring.

Index.HTML is just a simple Form to submit data to Rest Services and print out back on the same page.

I am getting the following error:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

http://localhost:8080/upload

App.js

```js
var helloApp = angular.module("SG", [ 'ngResource' ]);
helloApp.controller("HttpController", [ '$scope', '$resource',
  function($scope, $resource) {
   $scope.users = [];
   
   $scope.saveUser = function(){
    $scope.users.push({ 'name':$scope.name, 'username': $scope.username, 'size':$scope.size, 'email':$scope.email });  
    // Create a resource class object
    //
    var User = $resource('/upload');
    // Call action method (save) on the class 
    //
    User.save({name:$scope.firstname,username:$scope.username,size:$scope.size,email:$scope.email}, function(response){
     $scope.message = response.message;
    });
    
    $scope.firstname='';
    $scope.username='';
    $scope.size='';
    $scope.email='';
   }
   
  } ]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html ng-app="SG">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src = "jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app = "SG" ng-controller="HttpController" >

<div class="intro-message">
<h1>First Page</h1>
<h3></h3>
<div>
<section>
<ul class = "nav nav-pills">
<li ng-class ="{active:tab ===1}"> <a href ng-click="tab =1">Submit job</a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</div>
<div class = "panel" ng-show="tab ===1">

<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    
    <!-- PAGE HEADER -->
    <div class="page-header"><h1>Open Source Form Validation</h1></div>
   
    <!-- FORM -->
    <!-- pass in the variable if our form is valid or invalid -->
    <form name="userForm"  ng-submit="saveUser()" novalidate> <!-- novalidate prevents HTML5 validation since we will be validating ourselves -->

        <!-- NAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="name" required>
            <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
            
        </div>

        <!-- USERNAME -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" ng-model="username" ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="8">
   <p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>
        
        <!-- EMAIL -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="email">
            <p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
        </div>
   
            <!-- NO OF HOURS -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>No of Hours</label>
            <input type="number" name="size" class="form-control" ng-model="size" ng->
        </div>
     
        <!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled = "userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
       {{$scope.message}}
      
   </div><!-- col-sm-8 -->
</div><!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

RestApiController.Java

@Controller
public class RestApiController {

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String provideUploadInfo() {
    return "Test Get run to this URL.";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String userName,
        @RequestParam("username") String jobName, @RequestParam("size") String nodes,
        @RequestParam("email") String email){
    System.out.println("hello");
    return "The company data (name: " + userName + ", employees: "+ jobName + ", headoffice: " + email + ") is saved";
}

}
```

Comment: If you check in web developer tools what's the request method that fails? Is it GET POST or OPTIONS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my method signature to make it compatible with JSON instead of string.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json",produces= "application/json")
public @ResponseBody DataPost handleFileUpload( @RequestBody DataPost datapost){

    System.out.println(datapost.getUsername());
    datapost.setUsername(datapost.getUsername()+"Controller");
    System.out.println("hello");
    return datapost;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",method=Request.Method.POST)
public @ResponseBody HashMap<String,String> handleFileUpload(@RequestBody HashMap<String,String> userdetails)
{
  System.out.println("User Details is : "+userdetails);
  HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
  user.put("name","example");
  return example
}
```

@RequestParam is used to bind the url value
@RequestBody is used for ajax parsing request body

Return type should be JSONObject or HashMap.

Answer (score -1):

Check the host If your project not running with root folder in server. Add your project name with the url.
http://localhost:8080/ExampleProject/upload